# Filter out elements in tuple from list of tuples

Tags: haskell

I have an list of tuples looking like this:

```
[("APPLE",["APPLE","BANANA","PEAR"]),("ANANAS",["ANANAS","BANANA","APPLE"])]
```

However I would like to remove any occurrence of the first element in the tuple from the snd list in the tuple. So I would like the list of tuples to look like:

```
[("APPLE",["BANANA","PEAR"]),("ANANAS",["BANANA","APPLE"])]
```

Comment: What did you try? What is not working?

Comment: I have tried using filter but I did not get it to work, firstly filter seems to create an unnecessary extra pair of list brackets secondly I don't know how to declare function parameters when working with tuples.

Comment: this looks more like a mapping, where you map a 2-tuple to a new 2-tuple with a filtered second iitem.

Comment: I solved it now thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I solved it using:

```
map (\(x, y) -> (x, filter (/=x) y)) list
```